# Vue JS loop with different components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue JS to make a list that has one generic list item component. If there exists a none generic component that meets the correct type a custom component will be used.

```
 <email-queue-item v-for="item in queue"
                          :key="item.id"
                          :item="item"
                          v-if="type == 'EmailMessage'"></email-queue-item>
        <queue-item v-for="item in queue"
                          :key="item.id"
                          :item="item"
                          v-else></queue-item>
```

The code above better illustrates what I am trying to do. The problem I seem to have is due loops first creating two list and then checks the conditional. Is there a way in due to pick the right component vase on the type and then loop through the list?

The data Used to display these components is like this:

```
{
    name: Email,
    type: EmailMessage,
    data:[
        {...},
        {...},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: using `v-bind:is`, check [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Answer (score 17):

Dynamic components make this pretty easy in the template:

```
<component
    :is="type == 'EmailMessage' ? 'email-queue-item' : 'queue-item'"
    v-for="item in queue"
    :key="item.id"
    :item="item"
/>
```

Comment: This works for me. Don't forget to import the components.

Answer (score 3):

If I undersstand correctly, you'd like v-for with dynamic component.

so check [Vue Official Guide: dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components), then the demo will be like below which uses `v-bind:is`:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('email-queue-item', {
  template: `<div><h3 :style="{'background-color':color}">Email: {{color}}</h3></div>`,
  props: ['color']
})
Vue.component('message-queue-item', {
  template: `<div><h1 :style="{'background-color':color}">Message: {{color}}</h1></div>`,
  props: ['color']
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {'component':'email-queue-item', 'color':'red'},
        {'component':'message-queue-item', 'color':'blue'},
        {'component':'email-queue-item', 'color':'green'}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :color="item.color" :is="item.component"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you really understand.I have a parent component called list which those two components are called in, and data is passed with a list type. If it is an email list type use email queue item otherwise use regular queue item.

Comment: The problem how it is right now is it is acting like I have to list and not one. This causes duplicate keys.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I don't understand what you said. probably you need: `<div v-for="item in queue" :key="item.id"><email-queue-item
                          :item="item"
                          v-if="type == 'EmailMessage'"></email-queue-item>
        <queue-item 
                          :item="item"
                          v-else></queue-item></div>`